# ZF2 Cannot extend from interface AbstractActionController

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-studio

Hello i have problem with warning in Zend Studio 10.
I create Album Controller and set

```
namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zned\View\Model\ViewModel;
```

After that i declare controller :

```
class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
```

**Warning is :**

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>
> Cannot extend from interface
>   'AbstractActionController'    AlbumController.php /zf2-tutorial/module/Album/src/Album/Controller line
>   8 DLTK Problem

But all work good. How can fix this?

Comment: First of all replace use Zned\View\Model\ViewModel; with "use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;", then post your full controller

Comment: Are you sure? Try that code with double quotes in ZFS and you will see does you can render...

Comment: i am 100 percent SURE, also for a file to depict CONTROLLER property it must extends AbstractActionController else you will get screen with bunch of new errors, also Zned\View\Model\ViewModel will never load viewModel unless you are too keen and created a new namespace as you mentioned

Comment: I say go in ZS and type that in some controller in indexAction and u will se. I try that afre this post. When i put double q. zs back warning and dont render view

Comment: I recommend you to use NetBeans as its the best for PHP related works

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Zend Framework 2 bug. Try your code to run and you'd see that it works.

Apparently Zend Studio fails to recognize the AbstractActionController extends AbstractController implements Dispatchable, EventManagerAwareInterface, InjectApplicationEventInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.

The interfaces have certain methods that are either implemented by the AbstractController or the AbstractActionController. My guess is that Zend Studio has not found all of the Zend Framework classes, so check the include paths for your application. Also, it might still be scanning for files so not all controller classes have been indexed yet.

Comment: I know what he implements but i say in above post. This all work but all time am getting that stupid warning.

Comment: My answer is not about the inheritance model, but the fact Zend Studio is not understanding this model. This is not a Zend **Framework** problem but a Zend **Studio** problem. Check your loaded classes etc

Comment: Ok Jurian i will check tnx for answer